# why settimeout blocks eventloop

Tags: node.js

Note: this is not a replicated post for those about settimeout, the key answer here is browser design options.

I am starting study node.js:
A simple example to test async:

```
var http=require('http');

http.createServer(
    function(request, response){


        response.writeHead(200);
        response.write("Hello, dog is running");
        setTimeout(
            function(){
                response.write("Dog is done");
                response.end();
            },
            10000
        );

    }
).listen(8080);
console.log("Listen on port 8080")
```

One interesting thing is its behavior is differernt when in command lind with curl and in browser:
In Ubuntu 12.10, I use curl localhost:8080 in two consoles, they response in almost same 10 sends.

However, I open two browsers, make the request at almost same time, but the whole procedure took me 20 seconds?

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nodejs one request blocks another requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197064/nodejs-one-request-blocks-another-requests)

Comment: @MattBall, I don't think it's a duplicate. This one doesn't do CPU intensive processing. Also, it works correctly using CLI (curl) for me, but not in Firefox.

Comment: Looks like browser isn't sending the second request until the first one ends. If you add a log statement to the start of the handler, it'll demonstrate this.

Comment: I edit the post because of new finding, it is differernt when use console with command curl and in browsers. Guys, please help me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the browser waiting, not node.js

If you run the server and request `http://localhost:8080/` in two tabs it takes 20 seconds because the browser waits for the first request to the same url before starting the second.

If you run the server and request `http://localhost:8080/1` and `http://localhost:8080/2` in two tabs it takes 10 seconds again.

Comment: Can you tell me more about how the browser works? Why they can not open the same url with tabs at the same time?

Comment: Chrome does not issue any requests simultaneously to the same URL, it is an implementation choice.