# Throttling, Multiple client requests, threading in node js with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to write a simple API manager in Node using express.

I have registered a simple route and I responded after 10 seconds to every alternate requests. I suppose I should get immediate response from every other requests which I am not getting. 
Even requests gets hanged as it should be, but odd requests should give me response immediately which I am not receiving. Kindly guide how can to do that.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var apiRoutes = express.Router();

    var i=0;
    apiRoutes.get('/',function(req,res){
      i++;
      if(i%2==0)
      {
        setTimeout(function(){res.json({message:"i responsed after 5"})},5000);
      }
      else
      {
        res.json({message:"i responsed immediately"});
      }

    });


    module.exports = apiRoutes;
```

Comment: The code above works for me.  Is there any other relevant code?  You're certain you're hitting this code and that your router is mounted to where you think it is?

Comment: routing is fine, the exact issue is that once I hit from two windows of same browser it hangs because of the this 5 second delay, however when I hit the same thing from different browsers (incognito mode) it works fine.

Comment: it happens when I initiate both request at the same time. Even number of requests should respond after 5 seconds, and odd number of requests should respond immediately. but when i hit this route at the same time from same browser one gets stuck (5 second, correct behavior) the other gets stuck too(wrong behaviour, it should respond immediately, however it responses after serving first call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853937/1968864).  So it appears it's the browser, and not the express code.

To test this, hit the server from your terminal (`curl localhost:3000`) and you can see it behave as you expect!

Alternatively, use this line `apiRoutes.get('/:number', function(req,res){`, then from your browser hit `localhost:3000/1` and `localhost:3000/2` and you'll see the behavior you expect as well.

Comment: waoooowwwww............thank you so much... i got my answer. I should have tested this behavior using fiddler.