# Express serializes calls with setTimeout?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following example (taken from the official express documentation):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('request: ' + (new Date()))

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('response: ' + (new Date()))
        res.send('hello world');
    }, 5000);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Now when I open http://localhost:3000/ in 3 tabs and reload all tabs at the same time I get this log:

```
request: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:52:15
response: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:52:20
request: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:52:20
response: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:52:25
request: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:52:25
response: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:52:30
```

So basically express is handling the requests one-at-a-time in sequential way. Which is not what I expected. Why is it doing that? Can anybody maybe confirm this is just a Windows issue as I am sitting on Windows here?

Also `setTimeout` does not seem to be the problem here, because when I leave out all the express stuff everything is fine:

```
console.log('request: ' + (new Date()))
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('response: ' + (new Date()))
}, 5000);

console.log('request: ' + (new Date()))
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('response: ' + (new Date()))
}, 5000);

console.log('request: ' + (new Date()))
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('response: ' + (new Date()))
}, 5000);
```

Which generates the log I expected:

```
request: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:56:57
request: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:56:57
request: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:56:57
response: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:57:02
response: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:57:02
response: Mon Feb 22 2016 15:57:02
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: node 4.2.6, express 4.13.4

Comment: it's not express nor windows, it's the browser. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/15853937/1685063

Comment: Ah well... many thanks! I was pulling my hair already! ^^

Comment: The same happened to me ! now, i always check with curl or wget

Comment: Can I mark my own question as duplicate? :)

Comment: I would have done too probably, if I weren't tied to the Windows machine -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can the problem be with your browser? I'm unable to reproduce. I installed it like you did with `express@4.13.4`, and ran this command:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/ & curl http://localhost:3000/ & curl http://localhost:3000/ &
```

I got this log:

```
request: Mon Feb 22 2016 16:01:15 GMT+0100 (CET)
request: Mon Feb 22 2016 16:01:15 GMT+0100 (CET)
request: Mon Feb 22 2016 16:01:15 GMT+0100 (CET)
response: Mon Feb 22 2016 16:01:20 GMT+0100 (CET)
response: Mon Feb 22 2016 16:01:20 GMT+0100 (CET)
response: Mon Feb 22 2016 16:01:20 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Comment: Are you on Windows too?

Comment: I am running OSX 10.10.5

Comment: So it really is the browser. Thanks! I opened the URL in different browsers and then it works as expected.